# iphone online database connection objective c

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, database-connection

right I am planning to make an application that connects to an online database to a certain website i have developed using php. the site uses MYSQL. anyways how would i allow the application on my iphone update and receive records from one of the tables with the ability to delete records aswell.

I am fairly new to programming on my iphone thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a webService which will connect to the database, and your iPhone app should be making calls to the webService ideally.

Duplicate of this question - 
[How would you connect to a Microsoft Access database sitting on a remote server through Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104655/how-would-you-connect-to-a-microsoft-access-database-sitting-on-a-remote-server-t/5104754#5104754)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you can go with.

First, you can build a REST API around your database that your application can call using the built in NSConnection or [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) classes. Check out this SO post: [How to write a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api)

Second, you can build a web service in front of your database that your iPhone application can connect to.